# Which Office 365 Plan need to be purchased for creating access web apps

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, office365, office365-apps

In access 2013, there is an option to create a web app.
My organisation is looking to explore this to way to take existing Access Desktop based application to Web, so that users can remotely also add data and view reports.

From this [MS Support](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Find-a-web-location-for-your-Access-web-app-05082c6a-9bdd-4048-bb6e-1e1f08a82749) link, I came to know that Company will need to purchase office 365 to use Access web app.

When I went to [0ffice 365 business plans](https://products.office.com/en-in/business/compare-office-365-for-business-plans) there are 3 types. Which one should I purchase? to be able to create web apps.

Our company has domain and website hosted/purchased at GoDaddy. Will we need to change anything on domain? in GoDaddy? If yes, Please specify what or point to post where I can get this info.

What will be other things required to be able to create web apps? Will one user licence sufficient? Will users who use front-end of Web app need to purchase additional licences?

For those with same Question,
Found [this](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/155/t/277500) post at MS Office Community helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be any of the Office 365 subscription plans:

[SharePoint Online Service Description](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint-online-service-description.aspx)

Comment: What will be other things required to be able to create web apps? Will one user licence sufficient? Will users who use front-end of Web app need to purchase additional licences?

Comment: Access is included in Pro Plus and E3/E4 plans for Office 365. Browse the link. It is _very_ comprehensive and just about every tiny detail can be located.

Answer (score 0):

After more indepth searching and help from link in above answer,

Office 365 Business Essential did the job.

The web app is completely different than the Desktop, SO will now need to learn fresh.